# Ошибка при получении файла из input[type=file] с помощью FileReader: Error: cannot read as File

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

В meteor-проекте я подключаю wysiwyg-редактор summernote и реализую загрузку изображений на Amazon S3. В качестве callback для загрузки изображения использую метод onImageUpload

Проблема в том, что при загрузке файла выдает ошибку метод readAsArrayBuffer

Следующий небольшой блок кода имеет полностью идентичную проблему

Шаблон:

```
<template name="editor">
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" />
    </form>
</template>
```

Обработчик

```
let FileReader = require('filereader’);

Template.editor.events({

    "change #file": function (e) {

        let file = e.target.files[0];

        console.log(file);

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); // ошибка!
    }

});
```

При выполнении кода file содержит данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В корне пакета FileReader идет проверка на наличие файла и его параметров:

```
if (!file || !file.name || !(file.path || file.stream || file.buffer)) {
        throw new Error("cannot read as File: " + JSON.stringify(file));
}
```

Я не понимаю, почему файл не содержит ни одного из следующих параметров, в частности path. Возможно проекту необходимо наличие некоторых библиотек? Что я делаю не так или что упустил? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Скажите, откуда вы взяли свойства `path`, `stream`, `buffer`. С спецификации их нет https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: Потому что filereader читает файлы, а не картинки

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вы совершенно правы! Сами имена свойств взял из корня библиотеки FileReader где очевидным образом идет проверка на их наличие, поэтому я и предположил, что объект файла в браузере должен содержать как минимум хотя бы одно из них.

Comment: @user233428 проверил ваше утверждение. FileReader обрабатывает не только файлы, но и изображения в их числе

Comment: Спасибо вам за участие. Я разобрался с данной проблемой. Как оказалось решением послужила обычная перезагрузка метеора. Я полагаю, что при установке node-пакетов, которую я проводил, метеор не подгрузил их должным образом. Поэтому работа библиотеки FileReader была некорректна.

Comment: Все равно очень странно. У вас у экземпляра класса `File` есть свойства `path`, `stream`, `buffer`? Откуда они там?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko какие данные содержит экземпляр класса на момент существования проблемы сказать не могу, так как самой проблемы уже нет. А код с проверками на `path`, `stream`, `buffer` я взял из корня пакета node_modules
[скриншот](https://2.downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/072bb349ce3ab90fd7e0c5e29c11685da11994f2f51049b2016082e37e0fda34/inf/XfWpNhdm6JEf71btbJ-6NW3IKfZoluFBNKZx-o1unjNIlTN29rl4yTqmdBKRHxfn674Jcrf_r5m00_Zq8OHKtw%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=2017-10-23_12-50-45.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&tknv=v2&size=XXL&crop=0)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.